# Sending an initial akka message

Tags: scala, akka

In below akka structure my `Parent` actor sends `StartMessage` to `Parent` actor which then sends `ChildMessage` to `Child` actor. On receiving `ChildMessage` a sys process to run an sh file is invoked : `"/Users/setup.sh" !!` In order to ensure the `DoM` message is sent after `StartMessage` I insert a Thread.sleep :

```
parentActor ! StartMessage

Thread.sleep(5000)

parentActor ! DoM
```

StartMessage is required to be sent initially as `setup.sh` executes initialization which the other actors rely upon. Is there an alternative mechanism which prevents from messages being send until an initial message is sent ?

All code :

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props, _}
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

import scala.sys.process._

case object ChildMessage
case object ReplyMessage
case object StartMessage
case object StopMessage
case object DoM

class Parent(child: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  var count = 0
  def incrementAndPrint { count += 1; println("incrementing and printing") }
  def receive = {
    case StartMessage =>
      println("Received StartMessage in child")
      incrementAndPrint
      child ! ChildMessage
    case ReplyMessage =>
    case DoM =>
      println("DoM")
    case _ => println("Parent got something unexpected.")
  }
}

class Child extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case ChildMessage =>
      println("Received Child Message")
      "/Users/setup.sh" !!

      sender ! ReplyMessage
    case StopMessage =>
      println("Received Stop Message")
      context.stop(self)
    case _ => println("Child got something unexpected.")
  }
}

object Question {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem("sys")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system)

    val childActor = system.actorOf(Props[Child], name = "RunServerC")
    val parentActor = system.actorOf(Props(new Parent(childActor)), name = "RunServerP")

    parentActor ! StartMessage

    Thread.sleep(5000)

    parentActor ! DoM


  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Akka [ask](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#send-messages) method to send messages to another actor but one thing you have to keep in mind is that the receiver actor must respond to the sender actor. So, in your case, you can either use ask as a sync call or an async call.

**Ask Sync**

```
Await.result(parentActor ? StartMessage, 10 seconds)
```

**Ask Async**

```
import akka.pattern.ask
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import akka.util.Timeout

implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)
(parentActor ? StartMessage).onComplete{
    case Success(value) =>
    case Failure(exception) => 

}(context.dispatcher)
```

And once you finished your work in the child actor reply to the parent actor by sending some message like `sender() ! "Work is done"`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the behaviour of your actor by calling `context.become`. Also, you can define two new `object`s to use when an unexpected message is received:

```
object Parent {
  case object NotYetInitialised
  case object AlreadyInitialised
}

class Parent(child: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case StartMessage =>
      println("Received StartMessage")
      child ! ChildMessage
      context.become(initialised)
    case _ =>
      println("Parent got something unexpected.")
      sender ! Parent.NotYetInitialised
  }

  def initialised: Receive = {
    case ReplyMessage =>
    case DoM => println("DoM")
    case ResetMessage => context.become(receive) // I made it up
    case StartMessage => sender ! Parent.AlreadyInitialised
    case _   => println("Parent got something unexpected.")
  }
}
```